# Angular ui-router optionnal parameters based on parent route parameter

Tags: angularjs, parameters, routes, angular-ui-router

I'm trying to set optionnal parameters on routes depending on a parent route parameter

My parent route

```
        .state('scoreboard', {
            url: '/scoreboard/:type/:period',
            params: {
                type: 'channels',
                period: 'daily'
            }
        })
```

When :period is 'daily'

Like /scoreboard/channels/daily/01/01/2000

```
        .state('scoreboard.daily', {
            url: '/:day/:month/:year',
            params: {
                day: "1",
                month: "1",
                year: "2000"
            }
        })
```

When :period is 'weekly'

Like /scoreboard/channels/weekly/01/2000

```
        .state('scoreboard.weekly', {
            url: '/:week/:year',
            params: {
                week: "1",
                year: "2000"
            }
        })
```

And when :period is 'monthly'

Like /scoreboard/channels/monthly/01/2000

```
        .state('scoreboard.monthly', {
            url: '/:month/:year',
            params: {
                month: "1",
                year: "2000"
            }
        })
```

But as scoreboard.weekly and scoreboard.monthly have the same amount of parameters they conflict.

I'm wondering if there is a way to define state depending on a parent route parameter.

Thanks and sorry for my english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your scoreboard state should just be `/scoreboard/:type` and then the 3 child states can be:

`/daily/:day/:month/:year`

`/weekly/:week/:year`

`/monthly/:month/:year`

Comment: I don't know why I have not thought about this... Thanks anyway, I needed an external point of view :)

Comment: np :) glad I could help!